# [Meteor call]: Loses prototype information

Tags: javascript, meteor

My Object uses the javascript Object Prototypes.

I defined the following:

```
Game = function(id, userId, tiles){
    this._userId = userId;
    this._tiles = tiles;
};

Game.prototype = {
    get userId() {
        return this._userId;
    },
    get tiles() {
        return this._tiles;
    }
}
```

I then create on the server a game through a meteor call and use the return value:

```
Meteor.methods({
'fetchGame': function(userId){
    var future = new Future();
    var url = "http://...";

    Meteor.http.get(url, function(err, res){
      if (err){
          future.return({status: "error", error: err});
      } else {
          var game = new Game(userId, res.data);
          future.return({status: "success", data: game});
      }

    });
    return future.wait();
}

});
```

The strange thing is, I can call inside the method the prototype functions:

```
console.log(game.userId)
console.log(game.tiles)
```

But not when the object gets returned:

```
   Meteor.call('fetchGame', userId, function(error, result) {
            var game = result.data;
            console.log(game.userId)
            console.log(game.tiles)
   });
```

`game.userId` and `game.tiles` both return undefined, although the object gets correctly returned (is has values of _userId and _tiles).

It is as if the prototype functions have been lost during the return from the future.

What exactly might be the reason for this?

Comment: When you log the properties in the method callback, try accessing them by calling the method. ie. console.log(game.userId())

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Data passed to or from a method will be serialized via [EJSON](https://www.meteor.com/ejson). The conversion is stripping your instance of its prototype data (functions are not serialized) which leaves you with a simple object. There isn't a way around this, but that's why it's happening.